# Make an existing measure cumulative when it's based on other measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to take an existing measure that I've created and make it cumulative.  I'm aware of the pattern for making a cumulative measure, but since this one is based on a measure that is Percentage multiplied by SUM, it is not working.  I've created a matrix to show the existing measures:
[image]
All of the columns in this table are working as expected except Cumulative Projected Return $ 5, the column to the far right above.
The columns are as follows:

- Order Week of Year: This comes straight from my date dimension table
- Merch Budget: This comes from a budget fact table.  It is a sum of
  daily budget numbers aggregated by week.
- Previous Season Demand    Count: This is a sum of the count of units
  sold from the previous    season.  I use a helper table to identify
  the previous season.  The    DAX formula is `CALCULATE(SUM(Demand[Ship
  U]),intersect(values('Ship    Date'[Order Date Season]),values(
  'Previous Season'[Previous    Season])))`
- Previous Season Return Count: This is the sum of the count    of
  units returned from the previous season.  It also uses a helper
  table to identify the previoyus season.  The formula is
  `CALCULATE(sum(Demand[Return Units]),intersect(values('Ship

  Date'[Order Date Season]),values('Previous Season'[Previous

  Season])),INTERSECT(values('Original Order Date'[Original Order Date 
  Season]),values('Previous Season'[Previous Season])))`
- Projected    Return %: This is just the return % for the previous
  season, as long    as the week of year is in the past.  The DAX
  formula is `IF([Current    Season Return $]>0,blank(),if([Previous
  Season Return %] - [Current    Season Return %]<=0,blank(),[Previous
  Season Return %] - [Current    Season Return %]))`
- Cumulative Projected Return % : Not important for    this discussion.
- Projected Return $: This is basically the Merch    Budget multiplied
  with the Projected Return %.  This correctly gives    me the
  Projected Return $ on a weekly basis.  The DAX formula is
  `if(Demand[Current Season Return $]<> BLANK(),BLANK(),[Merch

  Budget]*[Projected Return %])`.
- Cumulative Projected Return $ 5: This    is the measure I am having
  trouble creating.  I want it to be the    cumulative sum of the
  previous column, Projected Return $.  So for    week 29 it will be
  $16,068.49.  For week 30 it will be $25,549.86,    and for week 31 it
  should be $27,118.44.  Using the cumulative sum    DAX pattern my
  formula is this, but it is not giving any results:
  `CALCULATE([Projected Return %] * [Merch Budget],FILTER(all('Ship

  Date'),'Ship Date'[Order Week of Year] <= max('Ship Date'[Order Week 
  of Year])))`

Can anyone help me figure out how to create this cumulative sum?

Comment: It is hard to answer this question without a model to experiment with. If there's any way you could mock up a model that behaves the same way, it would definitely help. A cumulative sum works at the lowest level of your data, even if you're aggregating by week. So my recommendation would be to break down your table to date rather than week and see if everything makes sense at that level. Any problems at the day level could have a knock-on effect on your cumulative sum.